# video via phonegap on android

Tags: android, video, cordova

I have been trying to play video in my android application that I made using phonegap. I had several problems and so I have several questions.

Firstly, does html5 video tag work with phonegap? I couldn't succeed to write the html5 codes.
Secondly, what types of videos are supported by android and phonegap?
 Thirdly, I try to play a file whose extension is mp4. There is no scene on the screen but I can hear the voice of the video. What can be the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, the video tag is broken in most if not all versions of Android. Go star these issues:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22254 and 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8272

In order to work around this pain in the @$$ I've written a plugin you can use on Android to play videos.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html