# Phonegap Android Webview Video plays only audio

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, media

I've started to play around with phonegab today. When I was trying to capture video its working fine. Now I wanna show the captured video in the webview. so I was trying as below.

```
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        videoString = "<video width='320' height='240' controls='controls'><source src="+path+" type='video/mp4' /> <source src="+path+" type='video/ogg' />   <source src="+path+" type='video/webm' />Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>";
        $('#myVideo').html(videoString);
    }


};

// capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
};

// start video capture
function takeVideo(){
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:1});
}
```

but in the UI I see the player being appended but it plays only the audio not the video.. wot could be the problem.??

Any help appreciated and thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Check out my answer over here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536104/playing-video-on-avd-with-phonegap/9536236#9536236

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415602/video-via-phonegap-on-android/9415751#9415751

Answer (score 0):

you have two source tag for video, that maybe a problem as there specified two different type.

```
<source src="+path+" type='video/mp4' />
<source src="+path+" type='video/webm' />
```

so, try to remove one of them.